# Issues with libs on Ubuntu 16.04 (On Amazon EC2 Instance)

Tags: 16.04, kernel, cron, amazon-ec2, aws

I ran the AWS Inspector on an EC2 instance that runs Ubuntu **16.04** (kernel 4.16.0), some issues found and i did not manage to fix them even after doing the required actions.

Here are the errors:

**Description**: The blkcg_init_queue function in block/blk-cgroup.c in the Linux kernel before 4.11 allows local users to cause a denial of service (double free) or possibly have unspecified other impact by triggering a creation failure.

**Recommendation**: Use your Operating System's update feature to update package linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic-0:4.4.0-124.148. For more information see https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-7480

---

**Description:** In the cron package through 3.0pl1-128 on Debian, and through 3.0pl1-128ubuntu2 on Ubuntu, the postinst maintainer script allows for group-crontab-to-root privilege escalation via symlink attacks against unsafe usage of the chown and chmod programs.

**Recommendation:** Use your Operating System's update feature to update package cron-0:3.0pl1-128ubuntu2. For more information see https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-9525

---

**Description:** inffast.c in zlib 1.2.8 might allow context-dependent attackers to have unspecified impact by leveraging improper pointer arithmetic.

**Recommendation:** Use your Operating System's update feature to update package zlib1g-1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1, zlib1g-dev-1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1. For more information see https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-9841

Tried kernal 4.14 and 4.15 with no luck. Installed the required libs with no luck also.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Also hitting these. Did you get anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading kernel should work, but you have to note that it is looking at all installed kernels, not just the running kernel.

I had good luck with:

AWS-RunShellScript—

```
#!/bin/bash
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=1 -y || purge-old-kernels --keep 1 -qy
```

Possible remediation for cron: upgrading by way of debian package.

```
dpkg -i http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/cron/cron_3.0pl1-130_amd64.deb
dpkg -i http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/z/zlib/zlib1g_1.2.11.dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

This did not work for another package I was stuck with (man-db), which ... wound up having a rabbit-hole of dependencies... so I'm now looking at upgrading to 18.04LTS (which still hasn't fixed cron, but everything else seems good).